# Can not import csv to postgres (unexpected character found at location 4194303)

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, amazon-redshift

When I try to import a csv to my Redshift database, I get this error

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x75 found at location 4194303
```

Everything seems to be fine with the csv itself. The stl table tells me the error is on line 70269 of the csv, which contains this string

```
10:00:10,2014-07-28,Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0),Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,multiRetrieve,Not Listed,OS-Preview-logItemUsage,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,"[{""PubEndDate""=>""2013/12/31"", ""ItmId""=>""1353296053"", ""SourceType""=>""Scholarly Journals"", ""ReasonCode""=>""Free"", ""MyResearchUser""=>""246763"", ""ProjectCode""=>"""", ""PublicationCode""=>"""", ""PubStartDate""=>""2013/01/01"", ""ItmFrmt""=>""AbstractPreview"", ""Subrole""=>""AbstractPreview"", ""PaymentType""=>""Transactional"", ""UsageInfo""=>""P-1008275-154977-CUSTOMER-10000137-2950635"", ""Role""=>""AbstractPreview"", ""RetailPrice""=>0, ""EffectivePrice""=>0, ""ParentItemId""=>""53628""}]","[""optype:Online"", ""location:null"", ""target:null""]",192.234.111.8,DIALOG,20140728131712007:882391,1119643,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,Not Listed,"2014-07-28 10:00:10-0400,421 {""Items"":[{""PubEndDate"":""2013/12/31"",""ItmId"":""1353296053"",""SourceType"":""Scholarly Journals"",""ReasonCode"":""Free"",""MyResearchUser"":""246763"",""ProjectCode"":"""",""PublicationCode"":"""",""PubStartDate"":""2013/01/01"",""ItmFrmt"":""AbstractPreview"",""Subrole"":""AbstractPreview"",""PaymentType"":""Transactional"",""UsageInfo"":""P-1008275-154977-CUSTOMER-10000137-2950635"",""Role"":""AbstractPreview"",""RetailPrice"":0,""EffectivePrice"":0,""ParentItemId"":""53628""}],""Operation"":[""optype:Online"",""location:null"",""target:null""],""UserAgent"":""Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)"",""UserInfo"":{""IP"":""192.234.111.8"",""AppId"":""DIALOG"",""SessId"":""20140728131712007:882391"",""UsageGroupId"":""1119643""},""UsageType"":""multiRetrieve"",""BreadCrumb"":""OS-Preview-logItemUsage""}
```

Any ideas why it won't load?

EDIT: It clearly has to do with the number '4194303'. Many of my redshift uploads have failed, here is a brief sample of my stl_load_errors

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x3a found at location 4194303                                
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x63 found at location 4194303                                
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x6c found at location 4194303                                
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x22 found at location 4194303
```

All entries in the table where these errors occur of type 'text', and there are about 30 columns. The csv itself contains many thousands of records (quite large csv file).

**WORKAROUND (not a solution)**

I've found that the number 4194303 comes from the 4MB limit set by the TRUNCATECOLUMNS feature of Redshift copying. By disabling this feature, I get a "String length exceeds DDL length" error (which is why I use TRUNCATECOLUMNS in the first place).

So the problem is that many of my records are over 4MB, and redshift does not support such records if any of the attributes need to be truncated.

However, by using the MAXERROR 1000 option of the copy command, I am able to ignore the 4MB+ records and be left with a database that only contains the rows I wanted that are less than 4MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try your copy command with below options added

**ACCEPTINVCHARS ESCAPE**

Some times when you create CSV files from mac or windows they may contain special characters.

Comment: ESCAPE is not compatible with CSV. Using ACCEPTINVCHARS alone yields the same error.

Comment: is it possible to share create table for above table for which you are trying to load this line ?

Comment: every line is datatype varchar(650000) except the last two which are text. If there is an easy way to get the create table I'm happy to share it but I don't know how.

Comment: It seems to work if I do small chunks at a time. i.e. break the csv into 5 smaller csvs, and they move into redshift just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the EOL (end of line) character. I had the same problem today and the issue was that my csv had MAC EOL (probably a CR). I changed it to Unix (which uses a LF) and the copy went through.